# Why does a distant observer experience gravitational redshift and not blueshift?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, observers, redshift, gravitational-redshift

The model I am learning to explore Schwarzschild spacetime is where solution modes to the scalar equation originate at null infinity, propogate through a massive body (only inside the mass is the gravitational effect on the frequency considered), and out to infinity again. If the mass is collapsing, and the time region considered is before the black hole forms, then I would expect from physical arguments that the mode spends more time in a region where it is blue shifted than redshifted, because the mass is collapsing, the infalling region encountered will be larger than the outgoing region after the mode passes $r = 0$. So at null infinity there will be a net blueshift observed on the quanta.

This is not correct, it is redshift that results. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

There is a blueshift effect on the quanta.

I believe that the model used in the question "compacts" all gravitational effects on the quanta abruptly as the quanta enters the mass, and models this effct as a function modifying the frequency of the mode as it is "reflected" from $r = 0$. Because the reality is that the quanta will expereince a gravitational red shift from the mass due to the resulting time dilation for all time until it reaches infinity at the observer, it is reasonable to assume the blueshift, which occurs over a small finite region, is negligible.

There is a very interesting paper concerned with detecting this blueshift; "Gravitational blueshift from a collapsing object", Kong, Malafarina, Bambi
doi.org/10.1016/j.physletb.2014.12.022